# Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

There is an issue with my "Board" class. I've been searching everywhere for a solution but can't seem to solve it. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Error message is: **Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it**

```
class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    editing: false
  };

  edit = () => {
    this.setState({ editing: true });
  };

  remove() {
    alert("removing");
  }
  save = () => {
    var val = this.refs.editedtext.value;
    console.log(val);
    this.setState({ editing: false });
  };

  RenderNormal = () => {
    return (
      <div className="commentContainer">
        <div className="commentText" style={{ fontSize: "100px" }}>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.edit} className="btn btn-primary">
          Edit
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.remove} className="btn btn-danger">
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };
  RenderForm = () => {
    return (
      <div className="commentContainer">
        <textarea
          ref="editedtext"
          defaultValue={this.props.children}
        ></textarea>
        <button onClick={this.save} className="btn btn-danger">
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };
  render() {
    if (this.state.editing) {
      return this.RenderForm;
    } else return this.RenderNormal;
  }
}

**class Board extends Component {
  state = {
    comments: ["Comment1", "Comment2", "Comment3"]
  };
  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          (this.state.comments.map = (text, i) => {
            return <Test key={i}>{text}</Test>;
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  };
}**

export { Test, Board };
```

```
Index.JS:
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Board />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Comment: `(this.state.comments.map = (text, i) => {` Remove the `=`. `(this.state.comments.map(text, i) => {`

Comment: @NicholasTower it gave me this error now ./src/App.js
  Line 70:47:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: I overlooked that the parentheses are wrong. `this.state.comments.map((text, i) => {`

Comment: Thank you so much @NicholasTower, your solution together with Ian's fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  render() {
    if (this.state.editing) {
      return this.RenderForm;
    } else return this.RenderNormal;
  }
```

Here in your `render` function, you're returning one of the two *functions*, rather than the result of calling them. If you simply add parentheses to the end of `RenderForm` and `RenderNormal` (ie, `return this.RenderForm();` it should work fine, as then you'll be returning the result of calling the function.

Comment: I did that but it didn't really change anything. I never had any issues rendering the first class surprisingly without the brackets, it's only the second class with the mapping that I have an issue with

Comment: Wait scratch that, you fixed one of the two bugs causing this issue. Thank you so much!